# Shouldn't Object.clone() need explicit cast?

Tags: java, clone

Why **doesn't** Object.clone() call need an explicit cast? Isn't this an exception to the "downcast always need and explicit cast" rule?  I compiled and successfully run the following code using both javac command-line and Eclipse Helios with JDK1.6.0_29.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] original = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        byte[] copy = original.clone();

        for (byte b : copy) {
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        }

        int[] originalInt = { 11, 22, 33, 44 };
        int[] copyInt = originalInt.clone();

        for (int i : copyInt) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        String[] originalStr = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        String[] copyStr = originalStr.clone();

        for (String s : copyStr) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }

        Main[] originalMain = { new Main() };
        Main[] copyMain = originalMain.clone();

        for (Main m : copyMain) {
            System.out.print(m + " ");
        }
    } // end method main

} // end class Main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling `Object.clone()`. You are calling `T[].clone()`, which is overridden to return `T[]`.

[JLS 10.7 Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name
>     in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. **The return type of
>     the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.**

Comment: Thanks, once again we should not really on friendly GUI features like open declaration in Eclipse! ;P Thanks aix!